# Charting duration of time

Tags: excel, datetime, time, charts, duration

I'm fairly certain from the reading I did prior to this post that a Gantt chart is what I will need to create, however I don't know if that is the correct route or not.

Need to plot data of start and end times as one unit on an Excel chart, with date on the Y-axis and hour of day on the X axis.

The format of the start and end times are Excel numbers which is adding another curveball into the mix.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble visualising what you are trying to do. Can you show a sample of the data here?

Answer (score 6):

If the chart below is of the type you require:

[image: SO17868947 example]

then I'd suggest choosing a Stacked Bar format. There are two data sets for each date but the 'key' is that one has been formatted to be invisible.

Charting is something that I believe changed quite a lot between Excel 2007 (my version) and later versions so I hope struggling with times may be easier for you.