# How to create graph of time ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, time, graph, charts

Can anyone help me create graph of time ranges of all elements in Excel.
My data looks like this:
[image: Sample data]

Connected At and Disconnected At data values are in 24 hours format.

I want to make:
[image: Desired graph]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17871094/4717755)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do the bars have to be different colors?

[image]

If not, you can use a clustered bar chart.

[image]

"Connected at" is one time series, "disconnected at" is another.  The "connected at" series should be listed second in the data source window.

[image]

Format "connected at" with white border lines and white fill in the format data series pane.

Last step is to set the Series overlap to 100% in the Series Options pane.

[image]

Comment: Almost good, but scale is getting weird: [link](https://snag.gy/COvhWJ.jpg)

Comment: I can't see your x-axis very well, and I am not sure what you mean by "weird."  Is the issue that the major axis time incrememnts are seemingly arbitrary (every 7 minutes and 12 seconds, or something like that.)?  If so, remember that axis settings are in fractions of a day - one minute is `1/(24*60) = 0.000694`  If excel automatically sets a "nice round fraction" like 0.005, or something like that, it will be a weird # of minutes/seconds (`0.005 days = 7min12sec`).  In order to get my axis, I specified a major interval every `6 min =6*  1/(24*60)=0.004166666`