# How to create a stacked bar-chart of date ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, bar-chart, date-range

Can anyone help me with the following problem.
I get data from another program showing when a patient started and ended a certain medication. When imported to Excel it looks like this:

[image: raw data example]

I want to make a stacked bar graph which shows when the patient started/ended this medication, something like this:

[image: output example]
If I could get the name and dose as labels that would be great, but getting the data to display correctly would be a good start.

I've seen a similar problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630916/how-to-create-graph-of-time-ranges-in-excel) but I cannot get this to work for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are Gantt / timeline chart templates in excel. You can find it with File > New or Ctrl+N . And if you want to chart see if [this youtub video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfAOkXt5V_8) helps and also [this youtub video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZd3iXcueaI)

Comment: For continuing medication, you can mention stop date as `=today()` or better `=today()+1` which will update automatically.